# Access local storage with DOMPDF (WP PDF Templates)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dompdf

I am accessing local storage with JS and displaying the values in the HTML but when DOMPDF renders the page to PDF the values are not displayed in the HTML/PDF (tags are empty).

Error in console:
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

My JS code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
var UserScoreResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score"));
if (UserScoreResults === null) {
window.location.replace('/results/no-results.html');
} else {
var score = UserScoreResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var count = 0;`
for (let i = 0; i < UserScoreResults.length; i++) {`
if (UserScoreResults[i] == 1) {`
if(count == 0) {`
document.getElementById("answer-1").innerHTML = '<button id="q1" type="button" class="btn answer-btn m-0">STRONGLY DISAGREE</button>';
}
```

etc...

When viewing the PDF page in the browser and looking at the Local storage via dev tools, the values are not there even though it is still on the same site. Original page = [example.com/reference-page/] and PDF page (after render) = [example.com/reference-page/pdf].
I don't know if this is due to the render process of DOMPDF.

Is there a reason for the local storage disappearing that I am missing or am I trying to use a method that does not work with DOMPDF?

Comment: DOMPDF runs on the server and doesn't have access to the local storage of the client (= browser). If you want something from the local storage of the client appear in the PDF document, you will have to send it to the PHP script on the server that creates the PDF document.

Comment: Ok great, thank you. I'm guessing something like Transients could work then?

Comment: You just need the values on the server "somehow". You can optionally not use localStorage at all, and instead put things in transients, per user probably, however a more common version is to pass the values to the server when you generate the PDF.